# How to calculate mean for variables based on value of another variable?

Tags: r, dataframe, mean

New to R, this is the dataset im currently working with.

```
    i Y X
1   1 3 1
2   2 2 1
3   3 1 1
4   4 1 1
5   5 4 1
6   6 5 2
7   7 2 2
8   8 4 2
9   9 2 2
10 10 3 2
11 11 7 3
12 12 4 3
13 13 5 3
14 14 3 3
15 15 6 3
```

How do i calculate the mean of Y for the variables that have an X value >1. (Rows 6-15 in this example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a logical expression in 'X' to subset the 'Y' values and get the `mean`

```
with(df, mean(Y[X > 1]))
#[1] 4.1
```

---

Or use `fsubset` and `fmean` from `collapse` to do this more efficiently

```
library(collapse)
fmean(fsubset(df, X > 1)$Y)
#[1] 4.1
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(i = 1:15, Y = c(3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 
2L, 3L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 6L), X = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15"))
```